# Mysql Database & drop-down List

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to create a database entry screen with minimal programming. So far phpmyadmin as a tool does the job except that it does not offer options such as drop-down lists on fields whose values are populated from another table.
Is there any secure tool out there that offers simple operations like that (preferably written in php and customizable).

Thanks

Comment: your question is quite unclear what you want. do you want to develop a ui for CRUD operation? If you are familiar with Codeigntier framework you can use grocery crud [here](http://www.grocerycrud.com/)

Comment: Thanks, from what I've seen so far CRUD might be a good solution to consider.

Comment: phpMyAdmin will provide you dropdown if you have defined relations within your database.

Answer (score 6):

if you mean foreign keys, you can do as below :

1. Convert both tables into innodb, if they are not already.
2. View the structure of the table which will have a foreign key. Make the referencing field an INDEX.
3. Now come back to structure view and click Relation view.

you can see more details in [Here](http://www.binarytides.com/create-foreign-key-phpmyadmin/)

Answer (score 5):

Even if the tables are not InnoDB, phpMyAdmin permits you to define the relations via Relation view, provided you have installed the phpMyAdmin configuration storage. See http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#phpmyadmin-configuration-storage.